# Hazelcast's CacheManager not injected by Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I'm trying to setup Hazelcast 4.2.0 with Spring Boot 2.1.18, and those are my dependencies:

```xml
<depdendency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.18.RELEASE</version>
<depdendency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.18.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.18.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
    <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
    <artifactId>hazelcast-all</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The problem is that I cannot inject my configured cache manager into the application as it is not recognized by Spring. This is my cache manager class

```java
@Import(cachingConfig.class)
@Configuration    
public class MyCacheManager {
  
   @Inject
   private CacheManager cacheManager;

   @PostConstruct
   private void postConstruct() {
     MutableConfiguration<String, Account> cacheConfig = new MutableConfiguration<String, 
     Account>();
     ...
     cacheManager.createCache("cacheName", cacheConfig);
     ...
   }
}
```

And here is my caching configuration class

```java
@EnableCaching
@Configuration    
public class CachingConfig {
      
      @Bean
      public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        Config config = new Config();
        config.setInstanceName("test");
        HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
        return new HazelcastCacheManager(instance);
      }
    }
```

The error I get is

> No qualifying bean of type 'javax.cache.cacheManager' available'

but I don't understand why. It's like the Hazelcast cache manager is not recognized and injected. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are two `CacheManager` classes

Your @Bean returns `org.springframework.cache.CacheManager`

The @Inject is using `javax.cache.CacheManager`.

Here's some samples where it is done, maybe easy to copy them,
[jcache 1.1](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/jcache-1.1)
and [jcache 1.0](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/jcache)